# Modify bytes (Hex?) of a save file with C++

Tags: c++

Sorry, I have read a lot of Q&A on this site that are kind of related by due to me essentially just starting C++, only previously coding in C# and Java
I have a save file, and with a hex edit program I have found a value that modifys the campaigns save difficulty;
[image]

the '00' highlighted value is what I wish to change, I have seen examples but nothing that I fully understand enough to manipulate

```
    std::ofstream ofs ("/text.txt", std::ofstream::out);//("/JKSV/Saves/Fire_Emblem__Awakening/hack/", std::ofstream::out);
    //Edit item at 0000000D '00' to '01'
    ofs.close();
```

I know my question, put to people with proper knowledge of C++ is extremely trivial, but its still quite new to me

Comment: How do you identify  which byte to change? Any particular offset that needs to be modified? Any pattern that needs to be replaced throughout the file? First 00 to be replaced by 01?

Comment: Its at the same location every time, the highlighted '00', it always comes after '78 02 00'

Comment: So you want to replace the value at offset 0x0D?

Comment: Try starting with the [documentation for :`std::fstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream). There's a few functions in there that you really need to start reading up on.

Comment: Yes thats correct @bashrc and Captain Obvlious checking that out now thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to open the file in [binary mode](http://courses.cs.vt.edu/~cs2604/fall00/binio.html) so that i/o libraries restrict interpretation of the special characters.

```
fstream binaryFile("txt.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
```

You may want to check the available functions in [fstream](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_fstream/basic_fstream)

[seek](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/seekp) to the position where you want to modify the byte value:

```
binaryFile.seekp(0x0D/*offsetToWrite*);
```

Write the byte value:

```
binaryFile << char(0x01/*ValueToReplace*/);
```

Comment: Brilliant, I believe it worked, and it makes sense how you did it.
I did find the seekp function but since it was non-binary I wasnt sure if it was applicable or how to write it, thank you very much!